# Error code: 135 ,How to fix error: Could not find update-config.json. Run ‘webdriver-manager update’ to download binaries

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

```
[17:05:22] I/launcher – Running 1 instances of WebDriver 
[17:05:22] I/direct – Using ChromeDriver directly… [17:05:22] E/direct – Error code: 135  
[17:05:22] E/direct – Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run ‘webdriver-manager update’ to download binaries.  
[17:05:22] E/direct – Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run ‘webdriver-manager update’ to download binaries. at Direct.getNewDriver (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesprotractorbuiltdriverProvidersdirect.js:63:31)    at Runner.createBrowser (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesprotractorbuiltrunner.js:195:43) at q.then.then (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesprotractorbuiltrunner.js:339:29) at _fulfilled (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesqq.js:834:54) at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesqq.js:863:30) at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesqq.js:796:13) at C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesqq.js:556:49 at runSingle (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesqq.js:137:13) at flush (C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescriptnode_modulesqq.js:125:13) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)  
[17:05:22] E/launcher – Process exited with error code 135 npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details. PS C:automationDemoprotractor-jasmine-typescript>
```

getting this error at the time of debugging of e2e testing

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Can you provide more info to help you better. In addition, you should first format your post for others to understand.

Comment: Did you got solution for this issue, because I'm also facing this issue for the past 1 week and searching for the solution.

Answer (score 9):

1.Open Command prompt or terminal.

2.Go to your project root directory.

3.Enter the below command and hit Enter key.

**node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update**

This command will update the WebDriver Manager.

Answer (score 3):

You can also execute this command :

```
npx webdriver-manager update
```